# How to use if statement for a column in csv files with python?

Tags: python, pandas, csv

Sorry if this sounds too easy. But ı have a csv file with 3 data type
NAME,OCCUPATION,AGE

I have successfully imported the csv file, but what ı want to do is create a function whenever called checks the occupation and age variables and if the results match append a  new file.

EX.

```
    df = pandas.read_csv('customer.txt')

    if df.occupation == 'student' and df.age<=18:
        price = price // 4 
    else:
          .....
```

I am trying to figure out how to manage the data from the csv files in python , I am using Jupyter Notebook. But

Answer (score 0):

> what I want to do is create a function whenever called checks the occupation and age variables and if the results match append a new file.

You can filter the dataframe with boolean indexing. Then divide the filtered dataframe `price` by 4.

```py
df_new = df[(df.occupation == 'student') & (df.age <= 18)].copy()
df_new.price = df_new.price.floordiv(4)

df_new.to_csv('output.csv')
```